# Cordova "Origin: file://"-Error using and Android 10, older versions working

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, cors, same-origin-policy

I did an Cordova application sending geodata (WFS) to a server (geoserver) using ajax xml. The server has CORS enabled as well as CORS Origin-Filters set (which is needed for browser-version, this filter is at the moment set to *, so any origin allowed).
The POST-task works (!!) for up to Android 9, using Android 10 I get an "Error 403" because Android 10 sends Origin:file:// in the POST which means Origin "null" which causes this error.

I´ve read posts for hours and hours and tried to fix this, but I´m not able to do so.

Can anybody help me - would be very nice!

Here my js for the Ajax-Post

```js
transactWFS = function (mode, f) {
  var node;
  switch (mode) {
    case 'insert':
      node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([f], null, null, formatGML);
      break;
    case 'update':
      node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, [f], null, formatGML);
      break;
    case 'delete':
      node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, null, [f], formatGML);
      break;
  }
  var payload = xs.serializeToString(node);
  $.ajax('https://server.com/geoserver/database/ows', {
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'xml',
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'text/xml',
    data: payload,
  }).done(function () {
    //sourceWFS.clear();
  });
};
```

html-head contains

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data:">
```

config.xml contains

```html
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.3.4" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some days of work I could fix this problem by updating apache tomcat server to new version! This fixes the problem using CORS filter *

Answer (score 0):

Install this plugin https://github.com/globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr

Then set your preferences to

```
 <preference name="allowFileAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
 <preference name="allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
 <preference name="InterceptRemoteRequests" value="all" />
```

Comment: Sorry this didn`t work. Still the same problem.

Comment: Additional flags added, read the doc for all flags

Comment: I´ve read all docs but still having the same problem. I installed the plugin and set the 3 preferences. Anything else I can try?

Comment: Turn on XHR logging and see what's up.